# How can I specify a specific DNS server for ipv6 in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns, vpn, 16.10

I'm running Ubuntu 16.10 (with Cinnamon) as a VirtualBox guest on my Windows 10 work machine. We use DirectAccess as a VPN which routes certain traffic over a tunnel interface using IPv6. I have my networking settings such that I can ping IPv6 addresses from Ubuntu using `ping6 <the IPv6 address>`, but I'd like to be able to ping the hostname of the machine.

When I open **Network Settings** I can see the wired adapter and when I select it and click on the settings icon, I can click on an **IPv6** tab that looks like this:

[image: Network Settings > Wired > Settings > IPv6]

My instinct is to simply click the DNS > Automatic to off and paste the ipv6 address of the DNS I want to use into the box. But when I do that, it doesn't work, and when I get back to that tab, the box I put the address into has been changed to an ipv4 address and the box is red because it's obviously not a good ipv6 address.

I thought maybe, for some reason, this box wasn't supporting the shortened notation, but that's not it.

So what's going on? What am I missing?

Comment: Does your VPN assign you and IPv6 address when you are connected?  If not you cannot use IPv6 DNS servers because you can't route IPv6 then.

Comment: Both the host machine and Ubuntu guest have IPv6 addresses, but the VPN is only assigning the one on the host machine.